# How to drag select files in 17.10

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, 17.10

For some reason I can't select multiple files by dragging the mouse by mouse or touchpad since I've updated from 17.04 to 17.10.

Is there anybody who knows how to fix this?

My guess is that this is a gnome thing but it seems to me this should be editable/fixable...

I've been looking in Google for more then a week now and i can only find stuff on dragging files not select files by dragging the mouse....

Comment: Probably a Wayland issue. Switch to Xorg and see what happens there.

Comment: hmmm, seems you were right, but the strange part is that switching to wayland from xorg, results in still being able to select by drag... So maybe it was a bug that only happens after update but once switched back and forward fixes it. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like Pomsky said, switching to Xorg worked, but switching back left it working! :)

Also noticed that after a standby the issue returns so it also might be related to the touchpad kernel bug that began with Ubuntu 17.10... To fix this do: sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse