# Mouse drag highlight not working in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.10, ubuntu-studio, gnome-shell

I have installed Gnome 3 alongside Xfce4 on Ubuntu Studio 17.10 but when I am in the Gnome session I cant click and drag my curser to highlight multiple items on the desktop.

I am wondering if it has anything to do with uninstalling Nautilus. The distro came with Thunar (as a part of Xfce4) and when I installed Gnome I decided to uninstall it and replace it with Nemo (which I am still trying to make show its icons on the desktop).

If not does anyone know how to enable curser drag highlighting?

Comment: See if this works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975636/how-to-drag-select-files-in-17-10

Comment: I will try, just to add I am having this problem on both the Wayland and Xorg versions of Gnome 3

Comment: Then probably it won't work for you.

Comment: Just tried it, and no dice. I do wanna add that I can do the drag highlight in both Nemo and Thunar, just not on the desktop itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being self inflicted. In the process of trying to replace Nautilus with Nemo as my default file manager and attempting to get it to produce desktop icons (to no avail) I had caused this feature to deactivate. Reinstating Nautilus as the file manager in control of the desktop reactivated this feature.