# 22.04 mouse drag select not working

Tags: 22.04, mouse

In the newly installed Ubuntu 22.04
multi select files with mouse not working.
this was working in my old 16.04

Pls advice

Answer (score 2):

I do not see this issue on my end (updated from 18.04)

Anyway I suggest you to reset the mouse driver just in case by running below command and check if it works for you.

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/
```

Comment: No luck! still same :(

Comment: and btw, I couldnt upgrade, had to install afresh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found the similar issue but in ubuntu 17.10 and the accepted suggestion is to switch from Wayland to Xorg, as it says the issue may be with the Wayland display protocol. Link to the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975636/how-to-drag-select-files-in-17-10. If you want to know how to switch between wayland to xorg here is the reference: https://beebom.com/how-switch-between-wayland-xorg-ubuntu/

Comment: wayland to xorg worked for me +1, at least partially. because it works on the desktop files or folders, but not inside any folder. Inside a folder if I have multiple items and if I drag select it doesn't select as it's seen/behave on the desktop items..